# Solve by Mathematical Induction: $2^n+1 \leq 3^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm very confused on how to prove this.

By using Mathematical Induction prove that, for all positive integers $n$ the
following inequality holds: 
$$2^n + 1 ≤ 3^n$$

Answer (score 5):

You have to show that if

$$2^n+1\le 3^n$$ then

$$2^{n+1}+1\le 3^{n+1}.$$

Indeed,

$$2^{n+1}+1=2\cdot2^n+1<2(2^n+1)\le2\cdot3^n < 3^{n+1}.$$

For the base case,

$$2^1+1\le 3^1.$$

Comment: Could you please explain why your final answer is correct?  I think I understand it, but I'm a little confused on your "indeed" portion.  Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: @Bean: read from left to right and understand every equality/inequality one by one.

Answer (score 2):

For $n = 1$,
$$3^1 = 3 \ge 2^1 + 1$$

Assume that $2^k + 1 \le 3^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$.

For $n = k+1$,
$$\begin{align*}
3^{k+1} &= 3\cdot 3^k\\
&\ge 3\cdot(2^k+1)\\
&= 3\cdot 2^k + 3\\
&= 2\cdot2^k + 1 + 2^k + 2\\
&\ge 2^{k+1} + 1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Why is this answer correct?  I thought it would have to equal 2k + 1.  I also am not sure what your basis step and inductive steps are.

Comment: @Bean what is the $2k+1$ you are talking about? The base step is the case when $n=1$, and the inductive step is when $n=k+1$.